RTL8822CE disconnecting, authenticating fails
my WiFi connection drops every once in a while where the computer is trying to authenticate but can't connect.
Here is a recent log of journalctl -u NetworkManager and here are my system's wireless information.
########## wireless info START ##########
 
##### release ###########################
 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
 
##### kernel ############################
 
Linux 6.8.0-49-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov  4 02:06:24 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
 
##### desktop ###########################
 
Ubuntu on Xorg
 
##### lspci #############################
 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c123]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce, rtw_8822ce
 
##### lsusb #############################
 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174f:243f Syntek Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06cb:00be Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c123 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

In the log you can see the behaviour from Dez 01 13:28:21 on. It changes from being connected to disconnected and then fails to authenticate for a couple of minutes until it works again. I tried rebooting in between but that does not help either.
This happens a couple of times a day in all networks except my phone's hotspot. I tried different access points 5Ghz/2.4Ghz, but can not further specify as to why and when. Sometimes I got to trigger this when switching the WiFi channel on my access point. Also in 2.4 Ghz connections it seems to happen less frequently.
Also I tried a many things to resolve it (the network card seems to lead to many problems), like different drivers and disabling the network card battery saver (which as far as I can tell still is) but nothing worked.

Do you actually use % and @ in you access point names?

Yes, those are just (modified) random strings. I didn't know what to call them and like this they are easily recognizable. Do you think that could influence things? At work it is a normal name and the problem occurs there, too. So this does not cause it.

I think you would have better luck removing that driver from the PPA, any chance this is a Lenovo or HP?

Do you mean dkms remove? I tried that with both rtw88/0.6~ppa and rtw88/0.6~ppa and rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1~ppa. Now it is worse and I can't connect to the access points anymore :D My phone hotspot still works fine.
Yes, it is a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 14ARE05.
